# Expressjs + ejs and a tags href urls not working with subdirectory routes

Tags: express, ejs

I don't understand few things here for sure :)

Basic app structure as app.js file as:

```
const express = require('express');
const port = process.env.Port || 5000;
const app = express();
const path = require('path');

const mainRoute = require( path.join(__dirname, 'src/routes/mainRoute'));

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.header('Cache-Control', 'public, max-age=3600');
    next();
});

app.use(express.static('public', {
  maxAge: '1d',
}));

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'src/views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use('/', mainRoute);

app.get('*', function(req, res){
    res.status(404).send('404???')
});

app.listen( port, () => console.log(`Listening on port`, port ));
```

As well as a basic structure route.js file as:

```
const express = require('express');
const mainRoute = express.Router();

mainRoute.get('/', async (req, res) => {
    res.render('page', {url: 'pageone', title: 'page 1'});    
});

mainRoute.get('/pageone', async (req, res) => {
    res.render('page', {url: 'pagetwo', title: 'page 2'});    
});

mainRoute.get('/pagetwo', async (req, res) => {
    res.render('page', {url: 'pageone', title: 'page 1'});    
});

module.exports = mainRoute;
```

And on page.ejs template something simple as:

```
<a href="/<%= url %>"> 
    <%= title %> 
</a>
<hr />
 <a href="/"> 
    home 
</a>
```

Then adding a second route with the same route and page.ejs

```
app.use('/loc', mainRoute);
app.use('/sub', mainRoute);
```

So, now, the issue is when I load the URL:

```
http://localhost:5000/sub
```

then the links on the page render the view source href="/pageone" so, when I click on those link the page goes to a http://localhost:5000/ is not keeping the '/sub' set on the main route

For instance, in angular2 I can keep all the links and respect the sub folder with base url tag  set on the index

But seems not the case on expressjs

How do I keep all links on the page to the /sub or /loc path? without rendering or adding those to the ejs template?

I mean, having the links relative to the route directory?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`req.baseUrl`](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.baseUrl) to get the path on which the router was mounted. You can pass it to the `page.ejs` view and construct the URLs.

```
// mainRoute.js

mainRoute.get('/', async (req, res) => {
  res.render('page', { url: 'pageone', title: 'page 1', baseUrl: req.baseUrl })
})

mainRoute.get('/pageone', async (req, res) => {
  res.render('page', { url: 'pagetwo', title: 'page 2', baseUrl: req.baseUrl })
})

mainRoute.get('/pagetwo', async (req, res) => {
  res.render('page', { url: 'pageone', title: 'page 1', baseUrl: req.baseUrl })
})
```

```
<!-- page.ejs -->

<a href="<%= `${baseUrl}/${url}` %>">
  <%= title %> 
</a>
<hr />
<a href="<%= baseUrl %>"> 
  Home
</a>
```

Comment: Hi Arun. Are you available for Node.js consulting on simple questions like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67225319/node-how-to-download-remote-image-then-upload-image-as-an-image-file-for-form-s. Please let me know when you read this so I can delete the comment. Thanks.